# Navigation working very slow

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

On working with a navigation based application performing 3-4 push.
When I pop the 4 controller view and so on it takes much time about 2 sec delay.
I am performing some background operations for storing images in file manager
Even when I press back button then previous view nav bar gets clicked because of this slow navigation.
I am unable to understand the problem for delay.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can u try it on main queue `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { 
    navigationController.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
} `

Comment: Pleas be sure that background operations are not holding Main thread. More Over please look-out ViewWillAppear & ViewDidAppear in all classes.

Answer (score 0):

Try to write code to push on main thread,

i.e.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(){

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:yourViewController];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you are going from viewcontroller A to viewcontroller B then back to A from B , If you have some webservise call or something that is taking time in A then there will be a delay, try to avoid that and use it in main thread.

Comment: No there are no web services related operations. Just some background work of saving images in local file manager

Comment: Thats where your delay will be then

Comment: That is what I am doing.